# Need solution for a jquery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a novice jQuery user and i need some help in implementing a slideshow for a website. The images are to be changed automatically within a specific interval (i know about setInterval). I tried to use this plugin [CrossSlide](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/).

However, the images that need to be displayed are actually pulled from a database and they vary from listing to listing. This plugin needs the images to be given as arguments beforehand and this is not possible.

Also, image thumbnails should be displayed so when the user clicks on one, that image will be loaded and the slideshow should continue from that image. If i use clearInterval, i have to start the show from beginning. I am preferring this plugin because it has a Pause() and Resume() extension.

Comment: _"If i use clearInterval, i have to start the show from beginning."_ - do you mean `clearInterval` forces you back to the beginning (it doesn't) or you want to go back to the beginning?

Comment: clearInterval stops the show.. and if i call it again, it will start the show starting from the first slide. However, i want the show to continue from the point where the user selected an image. I may be completely wrong but this is what i observed.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that if you have some (probably global?) variable maintaining state for your show, i.e., keeping track of the current slide, then `clearInterval` will stop the show but not reset that state variable. So when you resume the show by calling `setInterval` again it should pick up its current position from that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the jquery cycle plugin and it has all the features you need and you can try it out from here

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

> the images that need to be displayed are actually pulled from a
>   database

Sounds like you're loading them with ajax.
in that case just load the images with [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) then in the success function call

```
$('#placeholder').crossSlide({
  sleep: 2,
  fade: 1
}, [
  { src: 'sand-castle.jpeg' },
  { src: 'sunflower.jpeg'   },
  { src: 'flip-flops.jpeg'  },
  { src: 'rubber-ring.jpeg' }
]);
```

with your loaded sources.

Comment: Thanks for the reply andy. I will be more precise. This is a property website and there will be many property listings. When a user selects a property listing, it will display the images related to that property. The site uses ASP.NET. The current implementation of the this features is done using Flash. I tried to use "Galleria" plugin but for some reason, its not working. The slideshow will be running automatically on start. When the user selects a specific thumbnail, the current image should be replaced with that and the show should continue from that point.